# C program containing user defined function, while loop and if/else structure

Tags: c

***Program (in C) is to ask user to input integers one at a time (0 is quit indication) and find the number and total of the even inputs/odd inputs using while loop, if/else structure, and user defined function. I can't get the user defined function to print the statements needed.***
(Code so far below)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    char name[30];
    printf("Enter name: ");
    scanf("%s", name);


    int num=1, even_count=0, even_sum=0, odd_count=0, odd_sum=0;

    while (num != 0)
    {
        printf("Enter an integer (0 to stop): ");
        scanf("%d", &num);
    }
        if ((num % 2) == 0) {
            even_count++;
                            }
        else    {
            odd_count++;
                }
    printf("%s,your inputs are broken down as follows: \n", name);
    return even_count, even_sum, odd_count, odd_sum;
}
 int output_function(int even_ct, int e_sum, int odd_ct, int o_sum)
{
    int count1, sum1, count2, sum2 = main();
    printf("You entered %d even numbers with a total value of %d.\n", count1, sum1);
    printf("You entered %d odd numbers with a total value of %d.\n", count2, sum2);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You never call `output_function`.

Replace

```
return even_count, even_sum, odd_count, odd_sum;
```

by

```
output_function(even_count, eve_sum, odd_count, odd_sum);
```

and remove

```
 int count1, sum1, count2, sum2 = main();
```

The last line to remove makes absolutely no sense.

and finally replace your printfs by this:

```
 printf("You entered %d even numbers with a total value of %d.\n", even_ct, e_sum);
 printf("You entered %d odd numbers with a total value of %d.\n", odd_ct, o_sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, first you should declare the output_function before the main:

```
int output_function(int even_ct, int e_sum, int odd_ct, int o_sum);

int main()
{...}
```

Second, the return value of the **main** must be a single integer value.
Third, the **output_function** return always a zero.

And don't forget to call the **output_function**.

SK

Answer (score 0):

You have some nice thoughts.

**You thought:**

- `output_function` is defined after `main` so it can call `main`
- A function can return several variables which in order:

  `return even_count, even_sum, odd_count, odd_sum;`
- And you can get the value of them by calling the function:

  `int count1, sum1, count2, sum2 = main();`

**But C does not work like that:**

- `main` function is executed the very first, earlier than any other functions.
- You cannot return several variables like that in C (in some other high level languages like Python, it is ok).
  `return even_count, even_sum, odd_count, odd_sum;` equals to `return odd_sum;`
- Similar above point, `int count1, sum1, count2, sum2 = somethings;` just bring you `sum2 = somethings`

Please clean these mess first and you might get the program work well.